# Ember.js: Properly update URL after transition from beforeModel

Tags: ember.js

I have a route that I am trying to transition to if the some criteria is not met.  The route correctly transitions every time, however, the url does not always update to the route's url.  An example of when this doesn't work is using the following code:

```
App.ThingsRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  beforeModel: function() {
    if(!this.authManager.get('hasPermissions')) {
      this.transitionTo('index');
    }
  }
});
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. open the root route `/`
2. manually type in `/#/things`, it will transition to the index route, but it will keep the url /#/things.

This also occurs if I try the same url twice in a row.  The first time it will change the url, but the second time it will not.

Appreciate any way to do this without manually updating window.location.

Comment: You say 'does not always'...  does that mean that it does sometimes?  Any messages in the console?  Anything up your sleeve?

Comment: If I am on another route such as /#/another, then I try to go to /#/things, it will properly update the url after the transition to index.  However, if you type in /#/interactions again after that, it will not update the url that second time.  It is logging "Transitioned into 'index'" in the console both times though (with Ember.LOG_TRANSITIONS set to true).

Comment: That is odd, because I am using basically the same technique to return to my index route if not authenticated and I have no issues- the URL updates properly.  So if it helps, you are on the right track, but something else is amiss...

Comment: Agree with Steve something else may be awry.  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/azimigEF/2#/ seems to work, you may have some other logic breaking the router

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? I'm facing the same issue, but it appears to only actually happen when attempting to transitionTo the index route